# Is there a machine learning framework that supports partial evaluation ie can return a function?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, performance, tools

Is there a machine learning framework that supports [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation)?

For example:

We train on `[model, year, km, ..., colour, price]`.

Today we call
`get_prediction(model, year, km, ..., colour)`
It returns the value of `price`, ie a number (or a probability for a label).

Say I would like to call
`get_prediction_function(model, year, ..., colour)`
It should return a function `price(km)`.  (That function returns a number.)

Essentially we are pulling out a dimension or two.

In theory of course it gives us nothing, it just postpones some calculation.  (In practice this small specialised object is very useful in some production applications.)

Comment: A probabilistic [generative model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model) can do this through [marginalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).

Comment: @Emre Thanks, it is logical that it can be done and I assume it has been done.  The question is really which production-ready frameworks support it today.   One could also approximate it with brute force.

Comment: When you say framework, what do you mean exactly?  Would programming languages be frameworks here?  You can use MatLab to create a function that returns a function, where the function you create stores the parameters you enter to be used in the function that is output.  This can be done in R as well.

Comment: No.  For example, Python does partial evaluation.  But the resulting function is not self-contained and thus not trivially serialisable.  So it's a syntactic capability, but does not make it possible to easily send the result over the wire, or call it a million times.  (As opposed to something like `price = lambda km: max(0, 300000 - km) * 42 + 1234`.)